# How To Calculate Start and End Points on a curve and Locate the Center

Tags: geometry, circles

I am working on an irregular polygon. What I am trying to calculate is the center location of the arc and where the start and end points of the arc are located.

I am working in AutoCAD so I can draw it, but I also need to be able to calculate it. The following is my work so far. If I made a mistake somewhere or am missing something, please let me know.

What I started with was by subtracting my overall depth, 19.875, by the finished depth of 11. That got me a difference of 8.875 for the one leg of my triangle. Next I took my overall height, 30, and subtracted the top height, 14.25, and the bottom height, 4, which gave me 11.75. Using SohCahToa, I came up with the angle shown. I think that was how I came up with it anyway. The 1" radius is a constant with user control so we can work this as a set number. I have calculated the bulge of the curve to be -0.16314903. The formula I used is: TAN((37.064450/4)*-1*PI()/180). That is where I am at right now. Attached is a picture of the overall piece as well as close up of where The issues are.

[Close up of the angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba5bY.jpg)

[Overall of the piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q71o4.jpg)

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3.664779=4.000000-\tan(37.064450°/2)$. See picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is the 2 from?

Comment: See added picture.